# Force Excel 2007 to treat all values in a column as text

Tags: excel, types

I have a large column of data in Excel.  This data should all be treated as text, but in some cells Excel is "magically" changing the data to numeric.  This is screwing up my vlookpup() functions in another part of the spreadsheet, and I need to override Excel's automatic data type detection.

If I manually go through the cells, and append ' to each numeric cell, it works. I just don't want to do this by hand for several thousand cells.

For example, this works:
Manually type `'209`

And this does not work:
Manually type `209`, right click and format as text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If changing the format of the column is not an option, it's helpful sometimes to create another column that's 'vlookup friendly' and leave your main column alone.

This is a trick I've used a few times:

Say your 'mixed' column is column A.

In column B, enter the formula:

```
 =CONCATENATE(A1)
```

or as Jean-François pointed out in a comment, the shorter version:

```
 =A1 & ""
```

And drag it down for to the bottom row.

Column B will be all strings.  The VLookup can then use column B.

Comment: Or the even shorter `=A1 & ""`. This works, but what are the benefits of doing this *instead* of formatting as text? Why fill up column B with the same data as in column A?

Comment: @Jean-Francois - sometimes there are cases where I need to keep column A with it's original data format.  In those cases having a vlookup-friendly column comes in handy.  I'll actually edit my answer a bit to make that a little clearer.  Thanks for the shortcut as well - definitely easier.

Answer (score 7):

Under the Data Tab, open the Text to Columns wizard and set the Column data format to Text. The destination cell can be set to the original data cell, but it will replace the original formatting with text formatting. Other aspects of formatting e.g. Bold, color, font, etc. are not changed using this method.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you for posting. In my case, I had a column with a mish-mash of letters and numbers. Some of those numbers have that little green triangle that says "number stored as text" (which is what I need) and some do not. Right clicking and changing the column format to text did nothing. The Text to Columns wizard forced the whole column to text exactly as I needed.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. This comment solved a problem I had been struggling with for 2 hours. I had a column of serial numbers that I wanted treated as text, but Excel was not cooperating. Even when I changed the formatting of the column to text, the charting tool treated it as a number. This did the trick!

Comment: This is a more correct answer than the above first answer.

Answer (score 6):

Setting the cells to "Text" format, as Jean mentioned, should work. The easiest way to do this, in any version of Excel, is:

Right-click cell, "Format Cells", "Number" tab, select "Text" format.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to paste the data back into Excel after I changed the column format to text. After the re-paste, my leading zeros were visible.

Comment: I tried this (after upvoting it), and it did not seem to work in Excel 2013. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the cells' number format to "Text"?

In Excel 2003: Format > Cells... > Number > Category: Text.

I don't have the more recent Excel versions, but it has to be something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above but didn't work. And then added an apostrophe before the number. Only then it changed to text from the exponential notation.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your data and manually adding a quote in front of your data in each cell is not an option you can use a helper column and write

```
="'"&A1
```

in B1, where A1 is the reference to your cell, and drag down the formula in B1 to the bottom. At this point you will see the quote, and you need to paste data in column B as values (CTRL+C & ALT+E+S and select values, or paste special as values from the top menu). Then find+replace a '(quote) with a '(quote) and you will have a column with values forced to text and a quote in front of each numeral representation of the number.

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Office 365 / Excel 365:

CONCATENATE is being deprecated and replaced by CONCAT.

This method still works, i.e. I need `7E10` to appear as 7E10 and not `7.00E+10`

Microsoft documentation source [here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60384&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)